# ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.8 port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ubuntu

Telnet to Machine B through the firewall. To bypass the firewall, we can establish an SSH tunnel between Machine A and B, so all the telnet traffic will go through this tunnel (encrypted), evading the inspection. The following command establish an SSH tunnel from the localhost’s port 8000 and machine B, and when packets come out of B’s end, it will be forwarded to Machine C’s port 23 (telnet port). If you only have two VMs, you can replace Machine C with Machine B.

I'm using this ssh -L 8000:10.0.2.7:23 seed@10.0.2.8

[06/10/19]seed@VM:~$ sudo ssh -L 8000:10.0.2.9:23 seed@10.0.2.8
ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.8 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Typically, `Connection timed out` errors mean the machine at `10.0.2.8` is not listening for incoming connections on port 22. Either that machine doesn't exist, or the address is wrong, or it's not running an ssh daemon listening on port 22, or something in between is blocking the connection. Have you tried any other debugging steps? Can you ping `10.0.2.8`? Also, it's worth noting that you typically don't need `sudo` to run `ssh`.

Comment: May i know how to add port 8000 in ubuntu?

Comment: hi, i'm not able to create ssh tunnel